# Windows: Installed numpy (conda): ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, conda

I've conda installed numpy in my environment, and it seems to be working in the command line.

Yet when I run a file which imports it, I get a

> ModuleNotFoundError

These are my packages:

```
(pandaenv) C:\Users\LorenzKort\OneDrive - ITDS Groep B.V\Documenten\Python>webscraper_test.pyTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LorenzKort\OneDrive - ITDS Groep B.V\Documenten\Python\webscraper_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
        (pandaenv) C:\Users\LorenzKort\OneDrive - ITDS Groep B.V\Documenten\Python>webscraper_test.pyTraceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\LorenzKort\OneDrive - ITDS Groep B.V\Documenten\Python\webscraper_test.py", line 1, in <module>
            import numpy as np
        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

        (pandaenv) C:\Users\LorenzKort\OneDrive - ITDS Groep B.V\Documenten\Python>python
        Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on win32
        Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
        >>> import numpy
        >>> numpy
        <module 'numpy' from 'C:\\Users\\LorenzKort\\Miniconda3\\envs\\pandaenv\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'>
```

Comment: I assume you have Python 2 and Python 3 installed?

Comment: I only have Python 3.7 installed

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pip3 install numpy`

Also, try running your script with `python3 webscraper_test.py`

Comment: Tried removing numpy and reinstalling it with pip3, though no result. With Python3 the same result. (I have an alias for "python" which calls python3, but I don't think that's part of the problem)